# React Native iOS: How to listen to incoming links and handle them when the app is closed?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, event-handling, deep-linking

I am trying to implement a tutorial I've read into my App. I  have set up a way to listen to incoming urls and handle them.

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}
handleOpenURL(event) {
  console.log(event.url);
  const route = e.url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '');
  // do something with the url, in our case navigate(route)
}
```

This works well if the app is in the background. However, the problem I ran into is when the App is closed, the `handleOpenURL` method isn't being called. I'm not sure if I am missing a step. Another possibility is maybe I have to add event listener somewhere else. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Have you added the support for deep links in your info.plist file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by using this

```
 Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      AppListeners.handleOpenUrl({ url });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the url-schemes in Xcode. Go to your project settings and under "info" should be a point "Url types" then define your link there. [more about deep linking](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97)

Comment: I did that and it wasn't working before when the app was completely closed.

Comment: It needs both as far as I know the url scheme and getinitialurl.